# MVC Razor form : data not sent

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, http-post

I'm trying to so a simple form to send some data. My form have a list of checkboxes and next to each box, a name and a role of person. What I want to do : recover the list of person that box have been checked.
 I've created a model that way to do that :

```
public class CoupleModel
    {
    public Boolean isSelected { get; set; }
    public String name {get; set;}
    public String login { get; set; }
    public String role { get; set; }
    public CoupleModel(String name, String login, String role)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.login = login;
        this.role = role;
        this.isSelected = false;
    }

    public CoupleModel()
    {
        this.isSelected = false;
    }
}
```

My form looks like this :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateInventory", "Home"))
{
    @Html.Action("PersonListInventory")
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Validate creation</button>
}
```

And the PartialView linked to it is this one :

```
@model List<MyApp.Models.CoupleModel>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered"">
    <tbody>
         @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].isSelected)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].role)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And then, in my controller view, I just want to list the name of the people where the box have been checked :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateInventory(List<CoupleModel> model)
    {
        String res = "";
        foreach (var item in model) {
            if (item.isSelected)
            {
                res += "selected : " + item.login + "<br>";
            }
            else
            {
                res += item.login + "<br>";
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Res = res;
        return View();
    }
```

But only the "isSelected" part is set, that's to say that login is always blank when displaying. Why isn't it set ? Do I need to do some particular binding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that's to say that login is always blank when displaying.

That's perfectly normal. You don't have a corresponding field in your form. You need to add it as a hidden field:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].login)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `@Html.HiddenFor(..)`s for the fields you want to pass along.

The result:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) {
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].login)

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].isSelected)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].role)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

On the side, please use the .NET naming convention.